# Как подключить базу данных к проекту который находится на VPS сервере

Tags: c#, mysql, vps

В моем дискорд боте содержатся команды которые зависят от БД, изначально я скачал свою БД которая содержится на myphpAdmin, залил на хостинг отдельным файлом попробовал
написать так: `optionsBuilder.UseMySql("server=мой ip vps сервера;UserId=root;Password=пароль;database=название бд;");` в поле database пробовал писать просто название и название.sql бд не сработало, есть идеи как подключить БД к моему боту.

Comment: залили базу отдельным файлом? на впс установлен mysql?

Comment: @ВадимАлександру да отдельным файлом я вроде устанавливал mysql я там остановился на установке пароля и всё ну там бред я чёт сделал

Comment: Так вам нужно установить mysql, создать пользователя базы данных, саму базу, импортировать в нее данные из этого вашего файла. Я не знаю шарп но почему то уверено, что просто залить файл с базой не работает

Comment: Убедитесь, что пользователю MYSQL разрешено подключение из любого источника, а не только Localhost. По этому у вас могут быть проблемы. и указывайте порт с кодировкой базы, 50% проблем в одно решите.

Comment: @OYBEKRUSTAMOV скажите поэтапный план, чтобы я мог подключить к своему боту который находится на VPS сервере БД

Comment: `.sql` - это не база, а скорее всего ее дамп, то есть скрипт, который создает базу. Загляните внутрь файла, и если он текстовый, то я прав. Вам нужно создать пользователя БД, создать базу и загрузить в нее дамп. Эта задача гуглится легко. А вообще вам надо учить матчасть, а не рваться напролом. Ваш вопрос говорит о том, что вы не в курсе, как устроен mysql, а устроен он просто, надо только поискать и почитать об этом.

Comment: @aepot ок, ток сегодня начал mysql юзать я до этого пользовался sql server который встроен в VS мне как бы удобно, а щас оказывается мне надо mysql чтобы бд привязалась к моему боту который находится на хостинге, я завтра отпишусь об своих успехах.

Comment: @aepot вообщем я создал mysql серв тип дал логин там пароль всё вроде норм папка Mysqld создалась и файлкики в ней тоже теперь у меня вопрос я через прогу navicat(это прога работает с бд для хостинга) создал новую бд теперь чо делать? в самом боте в строке usemysql указать ip где находится бд там лог и пароль и всё?

Comment: Вопрос не понятен. У сервера БД есть пользователи, базы и таблицы в них, у пользоваетелей есть логины, пароли и права доступа. Задайте лучше отдельный вопрос и предоставьте в нем максимум деталей. Но в сети полно инфлрмации про это.

Comment: @aepot всё робит уже

Comment: @aepot вообщем если я комплю своего бота уже хостинг то я получаю такое сообщение  Хост 'мой ip vps серва' не имеет права подключаться к этому серверу MySQL очень странно когда я скомпилил это всё в VS у меня всё работало